# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, bash, variables, exception, display

I have trouble running a Java application in my CentOS server. When I fire the command below:

```
java -jar the-application.jar
```

I receive the following error:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:218)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:133)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:118)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I tried to define DISPLAY variable using command below, but this time only the error changed and the command failed again:

Command to set DISPLAY variable:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Based on the recommendations from different forums, I also tried the followeing varibales separately, but there was no luck:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export DISPLAY=:99
export DISPLAY=:99.0
export DISPLAY=:1
export DISPLAY=:1.0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:99
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:99.0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:1
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:1.0
```

I tried "xhost + localhost" command, so that maybe it can help, however, I receive the error below:

```
-bash: xhost: command not found
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep xorg-x11-xauth || sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth`?

Comment: Hi, the output of command is: xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.9-1.e17.x86_64

Comment: What is the error message when you set export DISPLAY=:0?

Comment: @MaryamSaeidi
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install lightDm on your system as mentioned here:

http://siripong-computer-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/how-to-add-cinnamon-lightdm-to-centos-7.html

If you are running CentOS on VMware you should install related tools on your VMware as well.